error when building a harmony os lite programe

Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\bende\AppData\Local\Huawei\Sdk\hmscore\3.0.0_8\toolchains\install-assistant\aapt2.exe link -I C:\Users\bende\AppData\Local\Huawei\Sdk\hmscore\3.0.0_8\toolchains\install-assistant\lib\android.jar C:\Users\bende\Documents\GitHub\batchlorproef_eigenmakelij\software\watchapp\entry\build\default\intermediates\shell\default\build\res\res.zip --manifest C:\Users\bende\Documents\GitHub\batchlorproef_eigenmakelij\software\watchapp\entry\build\default\intermediates\shell\default\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml -o C:\Users\bende\Documents\GitHub\batchlorproef_eigenmakelij\software\watchapp\entry\build\default\intermediates\shell\default\build\res\linked_res.zip

And when I open the android manifest the uri is not registered
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
normaly the app should compile ,

adding http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android to the schema's and dtd's tab in the deveco settings i can get that to "work" but i can not that for the tools tab it seems
